# Middleware - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::handle()

Tags: lumen, laravel-passport

I am currently unable to protect my routes with the [passport middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#protecting-routes). I am using [lumen-passport](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/lumen-passport), a package that makes Passport compatible with Lumen. When I attempt to hit the following route:

```
$app->get('/test', 'Game@test')->middleware('auth:api');
```

I get the following:

```
FatalThrowableError in AuthManager.php line 294:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::handle()
in AuthManager.php line 294
at AuthManager->__call('handle', array(object(Request), object(Closure), 'api')) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 780
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array('auth:api'), object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 534
at Application->dispatch(null) in RoutesRequests.php line 475
at Application->run() in index.php line 28
```

My `auth.php` if it helps:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => \App\User::class
    ]
],
'passwords' => [
    //
],
```

The route is correct as removing the middleware redirects to the appropriate controller as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem turned out to be my routes were in the wrong format. So to debug I commented out all existing routes and added the code (making sure APP_KEY=xxx is set  in the .env file):

```
$app->group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function($app) {
     $app->get('/user/info', function() {
         $user = app('auth')->guard()->user();
         return response()->json($user);
     });
});
```

And the route /user/info worked without the error.

Then replaced my routes with the existing routes in the following format:

```
$app->group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function($app)
{
    $app->get('/api/v1/users', [
        'as' => 'listall', 'uses' => 'MyController@listModels'
    ]);
    $app->get('/api/v1/users/{id}', [
        'as' => 'list', 'uses' => 'MyController@listModel'
    ]);
    $app->post('/api/v1/users', [
        'as' => 'create', 'uses' => 'MyController@createModel'
    ]);
    $app->delete('/api/v1/users/{id}', [
        'as' => 'delete', 'uses' => 'MyController@deleteModel'
    ]);
    $app->put('/api/v1/users/{id}', [
        'as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'MyController@updateModel'
    ]);
});
```

And the error was no longer thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In your `bootstrap/app.php` file, you need to make sure to uncomment the `auth` middleware setup.

https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/v5.4.0/bootstrap/app.php#L66-L68:

```
// $app->routeMiddleware([
//     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
// ]);
```

If the `auth` middleware is not registered, I believe Lumen will attempt to resolve `auth` out of the container (resolving to the `AuthManager`) and will attempt to treat it as middleware (calling `handle` on it, which doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My `$app->routeMiddleware` does contain `'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class`. Inside the `handle` method in `Authenticate.php` there is code that gets called whenever I add the `auth` middleware to a route but my goal is to get the Passport `auth:api` middleware also working as I need that to validate incoming access tokens. Unfortunately attempting to append `middleware->('auth:api')` just leads me to the error stated above.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if you resolve your problem, but i had the same one and I resolved it adding the middleware 'auth:api' inside the constructor of the Controller, in my case UserController:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this code in Authenticate.php

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is in you app.php located in bootstrap folder.

There you should define passport middleware.

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'client_credentials' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class
]);
```

When it's done you have to set your protected urls to client_credentials middleware.

When it's done try to make request with token to your protected route and for example return Auth::id().

You will receive user id for this token.

Regards